# Android (Java) - How to authenticate users for a site?

Tags: android, authentication

I am developing an Android application (one of my first) that displays a mobile friendly interface of a desktop site. The problem is that the user of the site must be logged in in order for them to be able to see these parts of the site.

I do not own the site nor am I affiliated with them in any way but I would like to create this application for my own personal learning experience as well as to help the community of said site.

With this in mind, the log in form used to validate users is accessed via the site's forum which is powered by Invision Power Boards (ex: community.invisionpower.com). I know how to get the username and password from the users on the mobile application but how do I send this information to a login form on the forum/website and then "click" the sign in button programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, you will have to decide whether you want to do this in a browser or in code.

In code, you would need to probably automate an HTTP post like this:

```
    // Start up your network connection
    URL url = new URL("http://www.asdf.com/someFormSubmissionPage);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoInput(true);

    String userInfo = "username=bob&password=pass";
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + userInfo.length());

    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    // Send the actual data
    OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
    out.write(userInfo.getBytes(UTF_8));

    // Flush everything to the destination
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    BufferedReader connectionReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), UTF_8));
    String responseLine;
    // Collect the entire response
    while ((responseLine = connectionReader.readLine()) != null)
        response.append(responseLine);
```

At this point, you could do something with response, maybe save a cookie that the server sends back to you, or whatever you want.

As an alternative, you could open up a WebView and give it an address like `http://www.asdf.com/someFormSubmissionPage?username=bob&password=pass`

This would star tup a browser with the user logged in.

The `someFormSubmissionPage` would be found out by doing a `view source` in a browser while looking at the login page for the actual site. Details of username/pass would also be found this way.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. One last question pertaining to the last part of your answer though, I am unable to find this form submission page/the variables for username and password. Any other way I can go about finding these?

Comment: You have to be able to see what kind of data it is expecting and where it is being sent. Usually you can do a right-click->view-source when you are on the webpage to fill out the form. At that point, you really have to search for the field names, form action to get the data you need. Can you post the form URL?

Comment: I see, here's the URL: http://www.powerbot.org/community/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login

Comment: ips_username, ips_password, & http://www.powerbot.org/community/index.php?app=core&amp;module=global&amp;section=login&amp;do=process -- It looks like it is a post to this URL.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. So if I understand correctly, for the WebView I can make the URL it opens set to: http://www.powerbot.org/community/index.php?app=core&amp;module=global&amp;section=login&amp;do=process&ips_username=USER&ips_password=PASS ?

Comment: That might work. When you append extra parameters to the end, it does a 'GET'. It looks like this site wants a 'POST', but often a 'GET' will work.

Comment: Oh okay, well it looks like it didn't work so I'll have to find out how to send POST data. Once again thanks a lot, sorry for asking so many extra questions :P